# Program won't let me clear my listBox in any way [C#, WinForms]

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

As I said in the title, my program will not let me clear my listBox in any way, shape of form.
I tried:
`listBox1.Items.Clear();`

`listBox1.Clear();`

`listbox1.ClearSelected();`

```
for (int a = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; a > 0; a--)
{
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(a);
}
```

*I did put `listBox1.Refresh();` after all of those tries, it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide whole code specially where you are adding the items in listbox. `listBox1.Items.Clear()` is the correct way in normal scenario.

Comment: If the items were added using the ListBox.DataSource or it doesn't exist, you should have an exception, so it's probably a different ListBox, maybe a ListBox you actually added to another Form or you have two or more overlapping controls or [... further uneducated guess ...]

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to remove all the items in the listbox:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: I literally said in my question that I tried that and it doesn't work. It just doesn't want to delete any items in my listBox.

Comment: @VukMC How do you populate the ListBox? You haven't answered that yet. See the comments above. If you'r using the `DataSource` property to do so, then you should do `listBox1.DataSource = null;` to clear the list or deal with the data source to manipulate the data and refresh the control. to reflect that.